# Which are the differences between the use of new and a proper use of apply?

Tags: javascript

Which are the differences between this:

```
foo = new Bar(someArgs);
```

and this:

```
Bar.apply(foo = {}, [someArgs]);
```

being `Bar` a constructor function

Comment: One creates a new instance, and the other runs the function with a context set.

Answer (score 0):

`new Bar` creates a new object inheriting from `Bar.prototype`, while the `{}` literal is just an empty object inheriting directly from `Object.prototype`. Then the `Bar` function is applied on the object in both cases. Also, `new Bar` has little different semantics if the `Bar` function should explicitly return an object.

Check out [this detailed description of the `new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new#Description).